# path of file (URL of .html) calling .js

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to find out the URL of the .html file that called the include.js ?

I need to find out the location of the .html file that called the .js,

Is that possible?

Comment: Um, `window.location.href`....

Comment: Ontop of `location.href`, I have a really nice [jQuery Plugin](http://fiddle.jshell.net/SpYk3/2ZuTe/) that will get you the current site url. You can then make any url you need (for instance if you know the name of the included html file) as easy as `$.myURL('myHTMLFile.htm')`

Answer (score 0):

would `document.location` suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `window.location.href` property which will return the location of the server side script that referenced the javascript:

```
alert(window.location.href);
```

Might return `http://foo.com/example.html` if that was the page that referenced your javascript file.

Comment: not quite what i was hoping to find out.

maybe i am not using the right terminology. 

my URL webmetrik.eu is being forwarded to a folder on my server.

xxx.xxx.xxx/klickpro/invisible/pages/webmetrik

Now, i would need to know the exact path to the actual location on the server, not just the directory starting at the URL level